# How to create a loop function using values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, jupyter, mean-square-error

I have created a dictionary in python which takes various files from a folder I have on my local machine. Each key in the dictionary represents the different files so when I run for example:

```
d['file1']
```

The output of running the line above looks something like this:

```
Date         Total
01/02/2010   500
02/02/2010   400
03/02/2010   360
04/02/2010   170
```

Can I create a loop function which takes the dictionary values from the 'Total' column for each of the Keys so that I can output the mean squared error given to each file just by running the code once? I want to focus mainly on the Total column as this will be used for the mathematic functions I would like to carry out.

I'm hoping that if I have 3 values in my dictionary, the function will loop 3 times and then the mean square error total will be printed along with the name of the file. I.e. an output like this

```
File 1 - Mean Square error is 89.1
File 2 - Mean Square error is 102.5
File 3 - Mean Square error is 111
```

Thank you.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, it's just two easy tasks being combined, which is why we have computers. for df in d.values(): computeaverage(df)

Comment: What I mean about the value is the number that has been recorded per date in each Dataframe. I know that doing something like "d['file1'][Total]" will list out all of the numbers which have been included within the df. How can I integrate this into a function to carry out what I stated in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each value in the dict is a dataframe, you can simply iterate over the dict and calculate the average with `pd.Series.mean`:

```
d = {'file1': pd.DataFrame({'Total': [1, 2, 3]}),
     'file2': pd.DataFrame({'Total': [4, 5, 6]})}

for file_name, df in d.items():
    print('{} - Average is {}'.format(file_name, df['Total'].mean()))
```

Outputs

```
file1 - Average is 2.0
file2 - Average is 5.0
```

Comment: If I wanted to work out the Mean Squared Error for the 'Total' column within each dict key by using the sklearn.metrics library, is there a way I can include this in the for loop?